# Call .Net web service from jQuery

Tags: jquery, .net, ajax, web-services

I am trying to call a .net service from jQuery and can't understand why data isn't being returned, please see the jsfiddle below to see what I am trying to achieve:

http://jsfiddle.net/brendan_rice/gtzkB/

Comment: Same-origin policy problem? Certainly a 500 error is being thrown, but that's pretty generic.

Answer (score 1):

You can't perform AJAX requests to servers on different domains.

To circumvent this, many API's allow data retrieval in [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) format.  Judging by the fact that you are currently trying to retrieve XML this may not be ideal for you.  Unfortunately it is the only solution unless your client script sits on the same domain as your API.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get a response back. The URL appeared to be set up wrong. Try this http://jsfiddle.net/gtzkB/15/